# Variables in module using colons

Tags: 7, entities

I think this may be related to using "tokens" when developing a module, but I am seeing this:

```
'og:updated_time' => array('value' => '[node:changed:custom:c]'),
```

The question I have is about:  [node:changed:custom:c]

What is this? What is it even called?

In my particular case, I am adjusting a module to retrieve a new value from a custom field.

```
'og:image' => array('value' => '[node:field_social_image]')
```

I have successfully used this for other custom fields, using the exact same syntax, but this one does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the tokens, more specific a custom/dynamic tokens implemented by Drupal core (`token.inc`) and managed by [Token](https://www.drupal.org/project/token) module.

See: [List of tokens](https://www.drupal.org/node/390482) page for more details:

> Custom format `[node:changed:custom:?]`   "`?`" is a single, unquoted [PHP date formatting character](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). Use this token multiple times to build a full custom format.

Comment: Interesting! Hope it's OK I added that link in your answer ...

Answer (score 1):

If your `field_social_image` is not a date field (it's probably an image field ...), and taking into consideration the accepted answer from [kenorb](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/1908/kenorb), it would explain why that that "`c`" doesn't work.

Because it's a [PHP date formatting character](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php), i.e. related to "***ISO 8601 date (added in PHP 5)   2004-02-12T15:19:21+00:00***"

In other words: use "`c`" only for date fields.